# Getting list of values from same index in a 4D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Lets say I have a 3D array with the shape of `(3, 3, 3)` (a cube). Of these I have 5, so in total a 4D array of the shape `(5, 3, 3, 3)`.

I now wish to go into the first of the 5 3D arrays, and get the value of the index `(1, 1, 1)`. This needs to be repeated for all 3D arrays so that I actually end up with a list/vector of 5 values, each of them from the index `(1, 1, 1)` in all of the 5 3D arrays.

In theory I could probably do something like:

```
import numpy as np

xn = 2
yn = 2
zn = 5
pats = 10

array = np.random.rand(pats, xn, yn, zn)

new_array = []
for x in range(0, xn, 1):
    for y in range(0, yn, 1):
        for z in range(0, zn, 1):
            for pat in range(0, pats, 1):
                array_temp = array[pat, x, y, z]
                new_array.append(array_temp)
```

Although, in this case, I just get a 1D list of all values in all the 10 `(2, 2, 5)` arrays (in this example) instead of 20 lists (2*2*5) with 10 values in each.

All in all, I'm not sure (if the code is corrected) that it would be optimal in terms of calculation time in the cases where the 3D arrays might be `(100, 100, 100)` and `pat = 1000`. So I was wondering if Numpy had some kind of tool, where it could just extract the values from the same index in each 3D array and put them into a list.

Comment: So the inner loop produces `array[:,x,y,z]`

Comment: The answer to the first part of your question was easy, which you accepted.  But then your `theory` code went on to do something much bigger, leading to Divakar's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't

```
my_arr = array[:,1,1,1]
```

do the trick much more efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Going by the iterative code, which is `x->y->z->pat` and tracing it back to the input array that was setup as `pat->xn->yn->zn`, we simply need to permute axes pushing the first axis to the back and thus remove all those nested loops, like so -

```
new_array = array.transpose(1,2,3,0)
```

If we want the final output to be a flattened one, use `.ravel()` -

```
new_array = array.transpose(1,2,3,0).ravel()
```

Might be more intuitive and generic with `np.moveaxis` -

```
new_array = np.moveaxis(array,0,-1).ravel()
```

Or with `np.rollaxis` -

```
new_array = np.rollaxis(array,0,4).ravel()
```

Sample run -

```
In [45]: xn = 2
    ...: yn = 2
    ...: zn = 5
    ...: pats = 10
    ...: 
    ...: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: array = np.random.rand(pats, xn, yn, zn)
    ...: 
    ...: new_array = []
    ...: for x in range(0, xn, 1):
    ...:     for y in range(0, yn, 1):
    ...:         for z in range(0, zn, 1):
    ...:             for pat in range(0, pats, 1):
    ...:                 array_temp = array[pat, x, y, z]
    ...:                 new_array.append(array_temp)

In [46]: np.allclose(new_array, array.transpose(1,2,3,0).ravel())
Out[46]: True
```

---

**Memory efficiency & performance**

The un-flattened version is simply a view into the input array and as such would have no extra memory overhead and virtually free, as demonstrated below -

```
In [55]: xn = 20
    ...: yn = 20
    ...: zn = 50
    ...: pats = 100
    ...: 
    ...: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: array = np.random.rand(pats, xn, yn, zn)

In [56]: %timeit array.transpose(1,2,3,0)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 270 ns per loop

In [57]: np.shares_memory(array, array.transpose(1,2,3,0))
Out[57]: True
```